# How to access woocommerce order refund object when order is refunded

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to capture the data from refunds to write to a transactions ledger on GSQL.

So far I take the new order information from the woocommerce_thank_you_page hook which. Im stuggling to get the data for refunds though as teh call itself is ajax and I dont know where to hook into that to dump data and build up my function.

Im call the following action:

```
//Hook into the order_refunded action, assuming this is called during partial and full refunds

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', [$this, 'refund_items_mysql_insert'], 10, 2);

public function refund_items_mysql_insert($order_id, $refund_id){

    //Setup the order data
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $refunds = $order->get_refunds($refund_id);

    echo json_encode($order);
    die();
    

}
```

Im expecting to see some data (refunds) returned into the network tab in chrome. However, the refund is processed, the page reloads and I get no response (preserve log turned on).

Comment: I don’t think dumping data and then “getting outta here” via `die` makes much sense here to begin with. If you check where that hook gets executed, that’s inside a method that is supposed to _return_ $refund afterwards - if you just kill the script, then you can’t really expect the rest to work properly. If you need to figure out what data you actually got in that situation, then either step through in a live debugger - or log data to a _file_, so that you can inspect it there afterwards.

Comment: Usually I would just print_r($var) and kill it so I can see the data on screen. I want to see what the key names are etc so when I biuld my PDO statement I know what to put in there.

Comment: The page reloading is probably due to the fact that this was an AJAX request to begin with - so it probably expects a very specific (JSON) response that indicates success, and if you make the system respond with other random stuff, that might make it think something went wrong with this background request, and it attempts a normal form submit as a “backup”.

Comment: If you’re not happy with live debugging or writing to a file - then you could also go and do a bit of reading up on what to expect first. If you look up the `get_refunds` method, you’ll find the info that it will return an array of `WC_Order_Refund` objects - and what properties and methods those in turn expose, is likely also documented somewhere.

Comment: Enable Wordpress debug and use `debug_log()`

Comment: Its always enabled on local, but surely this will only show errors. Im not looking to dump errors, Im looking to get data and show it on screen as I develop my solution.